# Power series involving complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that

$1 + \binom{m+1}{1}z + \binom{m+2}{2}z^2 +...+ \binom{m+n}{n}z^n +... = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}$

for non-negative integers $m$ and $|z| < 1$.

Comment: All I could think of was induction, but not sure how to approach with 3 variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: start with the geometric series:

$$1+z+z^2+\ldots = \frac{1}{1-z}$$

and differentiate. For example,

$$1+2 z+3 z^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$

$$2+(3)(2)z+(4)(3)z^2+\ldots=\frac{2}{(1-z)^3} \implies 1+\binom{3}{1} z+\binom{4}{2}z^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$$

Differentiate $m$ times to get your result.

Comment: I like that approach but the binomial terms, how can I show they're equal to the coefficients?

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generating series/combinatorial approach.

So you know that 
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n\qquad\forall |z|<1.
$$

Recall that if two series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0}b_n$ converge absolutely, then the Cauchy product satifies
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\cdot \sum_{n\geq 0}b_n=\sum_{n\geq 0}c_n
$$
where the rhs converges absolutely with coefficients given by
$$
c_n=\sum_{k+l=n}a_kb_l.
$$

Applying this $m$ times to your initial power series, you get
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^m=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n(m)z^n\qquad\forall |z|<1
$$
with
$$
c_n(m)=\sum_{k_1+\ldots+k_m=n}1=\binom{m+n-1}{n}.
$$
The last equality is a well-know combinatorial formula: the number of $m$-uples $(k_1,\ldots,k_m)$ of nonnegative integers with sum equal to $n$ is the number of ways of picking $m-1$ balls among $m+n-1$ balls. That is $\binom{m+n-1}{n}$.